# Private Gitlab Runner for code quality without Docker-in-Docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to run the code quality widget in our repo. Actually i want to register an gitlab runner on my kubernetes cluster to execute docker builds. I am trying to install the gitlab runner via Kubernetes Helm Charts.

this is my helm chart: `

```
gitlabUrl: https://blabla/


runnerRegistrationToken: blabla

runners:
  config: |
    [[runners]]
      [runners.docker]
        tls_verify = false
        image = "docker:stable"
        privileged = false
        disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
        oom_kill_disable = false
        disable_cache = false
        volumes = ["/cache", "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/tmp/builds:/tmp/builds"]
        shm_size = 0
            [runners.cache]
              Type = "s3"
              Path = "runner"
              Shared = true
              [runners.cache.s3]
                ServerAddress = "s3.amazonaws.com"
                BucketName = "blabla"
                BucketLocation = "us-west-1"
                Insecure = false

imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

unfortunately this does not work. i get the output *Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://localhost:2375. Is the docker daemon running?*

Can anyone please help with the correct configuration for this problem?

my sources are:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/code_quality.html#set-up-a-private-runner-for-code-quality-without-docker-in-docker

https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/kubernetes.html

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab-runner/blob/master/values.yaml

Thanks in advance. You are my last hope

Answer (score 1):

docker daemon error can be resolved by using the following code:

```
privileged = true
```